# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty R(x) \log x$ where $R(x) = \frac1{x^2}R(\frac1x)$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

In some old notes of mine I found the following interesting result

> **Proposition:** $$ I:= \int_0^\infty R(x) \log x \, \mathrm{d}x = 0, $$
>
> when $R(x)$ is a function satisfying the functional equation
>
> $$R(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} R\Bigr(\frac{1}{x}\Bigl).$$

For instance if $R(x) = 1$ then the result is obviously false. Is it enough to require that $\int_0^\infty R(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ converges to ensure $I$ converges?

- *What are the weakest restrictions we need to impose upon $R(x)$ to ensure that $I$ convergences?*

Comment: Note that $x-x=0$ only when $x$ is a finite number. I would say the weakest restriction is $\int^1_0 f(x)\log x dx$ converges.

Comment: @Szeto would it be true that convergence of $\int_0^\infty R(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ implies convergence of $\int_0^\infty R(x) \log x\,\mathrm{d}x$?